# How do i restrict my admin from viewing a normal user page using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a page for users named game.php, where they can update their profile etc. So when the admin logs in, they can still access game.php but I do not want them to do so. How do I prevent it?

I have 2 different log in page, 1 for normal users (logreg.php), 1 for admin (admin.php)

This is my game.php codes, where they restrict all users so I even if I am a normal user, it redirects me back to logreg.php, when I am supposed to be able to access it.

The status of the user will be "gamer" - a normal user OR
"admin" - for admin log in.

```
    <?php
      session_start();
      ob_start();

      If (!isset($_SESSION["username"]['status'])){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['status'] = 'admin';
            header("Location:logreg.php");
        }
     else {
        $username = $_SESSION['username'];
        }

    ?
```

Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `if`, you are checking the value of `$_SESSION["username"]['status']` but in your code you are setting `$_SESSION["username"]` and `$_SESSION['status']`. You probably meant the `if` to read:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION["username"], $_SESSION['status'])) {
```

to check that both `$_SESSION` variables were set.

Comment: This works! Thank you! Could you also help me with what I just edited into this post? :) Thanks in advance again!!!

Comment: @LearningJavascript typically once a question is answered, if you want to ask another question you should do that rather than editing the existing question. As a bonus you get 2 reputation for every answer you accept. More questions = more reputation!

Comment: I can't post another questions within 90 minutes :(

Comment: Well you will probably want to have different versions of the code in your `admin.php` and `gamer.php`. In the `admin.php` you will need to check that the user is not a gamer, and vice versa in `gamer.php`. If they don't meet the test, redirect them to the page they should be going to.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();
  ob_start();

  If (isset($_SESSION["username"]['status'] && isset($_SESSION["username"]['status']=="admin")){
        header("Location:logreg.php");
    }
?>
```

try this code :)

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead) in /home/mp01/public_html/game.php on line 5

This error is appearing now :(

Comment: <?php
      session_start();
      ob_start();

      If (isset($_SESSION["username"]['status']) && $_SESSION["username"]['status']=="admin"){
            header("Location:logreg.php");
        }
    ?>